# Tensorflow Error when using tf.gradients and tf.hessian: TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, nonetype, hessian-matrix

I just started learning tensorflow and came across the following error when using the tf.gradients and tf.hessain functions. Given below is the code and error for tf.gradients.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = (2,2))
b = [[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]]
c = a[0,0]*a[0,1]*a[1,0] + a[0,1]*a[1,0]*a[1,1]
e = tf.reshape(b,[4])
d = tf.gradients(c,e)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(d,feed_dict={a:b}))
```

I get the following error for the last line

```
>>> print(sess.run(d,feed_dict={a:b}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/share/apps/tensorflow/20170218/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/share/apps/tensorflow/20170218/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 952, in _run
    fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
  File "/share/apps/tensorflow/20170218/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 408, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/share/apps/tensorflow/20170218/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 230, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "/share/apps/tensorflow/20170218/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 337, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "/share/apps/tensorflow/20170218/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 227, in for_fetch
    (fetch, type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>
```

any ideas as to how I can debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `c` is calculated based on `a`, not `e`. You could change the line of gradient tensor as below.

```
d = tf.gradients(c,a)
```

BTW, in your original code, if you print `d`, you will find it is a `[None]`